# Audio amplifier: output power higher than input?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, watts

I'm checking the audio amplifier [Behringer NX6000D](https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0CHX).

In the doc it says

> The NX6000D power amplifier packs 6000 Watts (2 x 3000 Watts @ 4 Ohms; 2 x 1600 Watts @ 8 Ohms)...`

In the [quick start guide / datasheet](https://mediadl.musictribe.com/media/PLM/data/docs/P0CAL/NX-SERIES_QSG_WW.pdf)
the required power supply is indicated as

> 220-240 V~, 50/60 Hz, (T 12 A H 250 V)

Thus the power socket provides 12 A x 240V = max 2880 W. How can the amplifier output 6000 W if the socket only provides 2880 W?

Comment: The amplifier can't push 6000 watts _continuously_. This is its peak output. After a short time at this output power its internal capacitors would discharge and the output power would drop leading to distortion.

Comment: Peak power numbers are used so that the number is double the real low distortion number. The peak output is clipping like crazy with a squarewave having severe distortion. TypelA mentioned momentary power which produces an additional higher power number instead of continuous output power.

Comment: If it's not bridged for each speaker, they'd better have \$\pm 170\:\text{V}\$ DC rails on that amplifier. At minimum. Otherwise, ain't no way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to the audio amplifier advertising.

First, the peak power of a sine wave voltage over an ohmic load is exactly twice the average power. They usually state the higher number.

Second, if you don't put a pure sine wave into the amplifier, but a real music instead, it can average as low as 1/5 or 1/20 of the peak sine wave power the amplifier is able to out. This is because the real music has beat and other dynamic patterns.

This allows the manufacturer to grossly underrate both the power supply module and the thermal design of the amplifier.

In general, your 6000W amplifier can probably continuously out as low as 1000W of a pure sine wave over a *pair* of 4-Ohm loads.

Now, a 12A fuse for a ~5A real load makes a perfect sense.

---

Defining a good measure of power of an audio amplifier is a real pain.

Most genres of music (and other audio streams as well) have pretty wide dynamic range, mainly because human ears have one. A typical modern dance music track can be 20:1 between the top power at the beat and the average.

A classical orchestra can easilly go as bad as 100:1 (in fact it is even worse, but the good boy at the knobs makes the life somewhat easier). There is an added bonus that the loud moments can extend for seconds and the whole audio tract should be able to survive the maximal power this long without distortion, overheating or a fuse blowing. Listeners picky about both noise and distortion don't help either.

Comment: I suppose the more relevant (and less marketing) value is the RMS value then (?). Is there a rule of thumb to calculte the typical RMS value from the peak value?

Comment: There is no such thing as RMS power in electrical engineering. If you want to use that term you need to define what it means and, then the fun begins @Philipp

Comment: The RMS thing (be it voltage or current) is invented exactly because of the complex relation between an AC voltage and power. RMS _power_, of course, can be defined, but it has little practical use because the power is already "squared" (the letter S of the RMS) current or voltage. (RMS = root of the mean squares).

Comment: The thing you want is simply *average* power. RMS used for current and voltage specifically because RMS current * RMS volts = average power into a resistive load.

Answer (score 0):

Audio power amplifiers for PA use are typically rated assuming a 9db crest factor, which is safely pessimistic with real music.

Basically the thermal design is for an amp of ~1/8th of the power the thing can deliver for a short period of time (How long that period is depends strongly on the quality of implementation). Now power input protection is typically fuses or circuit breakers, neither of which are exactly fast for small overloads, so this all works fine.

You actually really, really want your amps to be designed this way because a 100% rated power amp will never do what it is capable of while costing you masses of weight and needing a stupidly over sized power feed that is also never fully utilised.

Of course, back in the 1970s the FTC in the US managed to come up with a way of specifying hifi amps that basically makes no sense either mathematically (RMS POWER?) or from the perspective of telling me what I want to know as a consumer! They specified what amounts to continuous tone power (The called it RMS!), but for most listening I don't care about that, I want to not clip on the peaks.

Answer (score 0):

Pmax (peak amplifier watts) x 0.707 = Prms (average power) x 0.8 (vol knob 80% or wherever clipping begins) = max. true listening listening power level.

My JBL PRX 812 is rated at 1500 W, achieved by two amps, tweeter horn and woofer.
1500 ÷ 2 = 750 W per amplifier max., however, input power is 300 W.

Since output power can't exceed input power, 300 W max. x 0.707 = 212.1 W RMS x 0.8 (80% volume knob) = 169.68 W max. before clipping, max. listening watts!

So you could say the manufacturer is really taking advantage of a technically ignorant public with power items like all amplifiers, including PA amplifiers. Do the math first.

Comment: Output power can exceed input power. Not all the time but for peaks. And only for voltages and currents of pure sine waves, Vpeak*0.707= Vrms, but not for power. Music is also not pure sine waves, as peaks can be 18 to 20 dB above nominal. Yes, good idea to do the math first, that should apply to everyone here.